# Problema al crear el Jar y consulta para hacer un ticket de compra en Java, IDE Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, jar

Buenas noches, quería ver si alguien me pueda orientar para dos problemas que tengo, ¿Como puedo realizar un ticket de compra y que se mande imprimir directamente desde Java y la otra pregunta es porque cuando construyo mi proyecto hecho con frames, en ves de crearme un Jar, me crea un Winrar? Gracias. El IDE que uso es Netbeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No creo que te este creando un WinRAR lo que debe pasar es que el WinRAR reconoce la extensión .jar y por eso aparece con su icono, para comprobarlo has click derecho sobre el archivo, selecciona Propiedades y comprueba que extensión tiene.

Para lo del ticket, en su día yo utilice iReport para generar PDFs desde java e imprimirlo, dale una revisada esta librería de Java a mi me fue muy util.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

Lo del ticket es complejo pues primero deberias intentarlo y si necesitas ayuda para corregir algun problema aca estaremos para ayudarte. Lo del winrar es porque basicamente un jar es un archivo comprimido. Entonces lo mas posible es que la extensión .jar este asociada al winrar para ejecutarse, asi que no tienes ningun problema con ello. Es mas si tu le cambiar a un jar la extencion por un .zip vas a poder descomprimirlo normalmente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y respuesta. Ya pude resolverlo